# XML Webservice - what to do when JSONP is not an option?

Tags: xml, web-services, jsonp

Scenario: I want to enter an address (Sweden, Stockholm) into an inputfield and get autocompletion. 
I have found a service that returns all adresses belonging to a specific substring: it only returns data in XML and as far as I can tell, doesn't support JSONP. 
The service: `http://openstreetws.stockholm.se/LvWS-2.2/Lv.asmx/GetStreetNames?apiKey=DIN API-NYCKEL&streetNamePattern=Kun*&optionalMunicipality=&optionalPostalArea=&optionalPostalCode=`

Now, since the service doesn't support JSONP, If i understand things correctly, that means that I cannot call the service from my website, since that would be a Cross-domain request.

**Is there a good way to solve this?**

The only idea I have so far is to save the entire xml-document, and create my own serverside function that parses that document and returns the nessesary adresses. However, this seems like just reinventing the wheel since the existing service does just this already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the service isn't meant to be accessed directly from a browser anyway, since it requires an API key. So you're better off making the request from a server. You wouldn't necessarily need to save or parse the XML document; you could just pass the response back to the browser.